# Convert mkv with AVC High@L4.0 to mp4 with ACV High@L4.1 or higher

Tags: video, conversion, video-conversion, libav

I am trying to convert some mkv files I have to mp4 so that they can be played to my chromecast.

Here is the information about the video files.

[mkv file information](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63844366/Capture.PNG)
As you can see that the video and the audio is already in the correct format for the chromecast except for profile level of the video.

I have been using this command to convert the mkv files to mp4 but of course it doesn't change the profile level.

```
avconv -i input.mkv -codec copy output.mp4
```

How can I convert the profile level to one of these Level 4.1, 4.2 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

It surprises me that the Chromecast can't play a video with lower level specifications… but anyway, you can try an app like this [H.264 level editor](http://coolsoft.altervista.org/en/h264leveleditor) to change the file headers. It'll make your video bitstream appear to be a different level than it actually is. I'm not aware of a *nix counterpart, but you could always [change the bytes themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519765/modify-h-264-level-in-mp4-stream).

If it doesn't work, you need to re-code the video, unfortunately.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level 4.1 -crf 21 output.mp4
```

See [this guide](https://wiki.libav.org/Encoding/h264) for a little more info. The CRF controls the quality. Less is better and anything between 18 and 28 is reasonable. For re-encoding, you'll probably want to be on the lower side.

Comment: Chromecast Gen1+2 plays H.264 up to Level 4.1 only. https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media But it does not mention a minimum Level. Can someone pls give a quick update, if a level-downgrade from 4.2 to 4.1 via above editor makes the video playable in an old Chromecast?